# How to maintain moisture on a substrate?

Tags: water, material-science, humidity

I know that different materials absorb water differently and dry differently. The simplest example is when washing clothes and putting them in the dryer they take different amounts of time to completly dry despite being under the same temperature, pressure and exposed to the same type of dry air. Obviously, the size of the object or material impacts how much water is absorbed and how much it will take to dry. However, I would like to know if there are other factors I can control to slow the drying of the material.

- I have a printer paper (regular) and I would like it to maintain moisture for a longer period of time. what can I do to enhance the ability to keep moisture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious factor is temperature, which strongly affects [vapour pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure). Water molecules randomly stick to the surface and leave the surface, with rates dependent on the concentration in the air/surface, temperature, and material properties. The equilibrium determines how much moisture remains, and pushing it towards the surface by low temperature, moisture saturated air, little airflow (otherwise water may convect away; if there is a saturated air boundary near the surface drying is slowed).

Many materials have significant bound water (up to 8% in "dry" cotton) that affect drying. Such materials will if dry suck up water and retain it, drying out the surroundings. So the mechanisms surrounding the paper better be fairly saturated or hydrophobic to keep from sucking up water.

Comment: Thx. Do you know if some types of paper will have a higher bound water effect than others? Also, what causes that property to vary?

Comment: I assume different papers are differently hydroscopic, probably dependent on how many -OH groups are exposed on the cellulose molecules (affected by treatment) and the size and shape of pores in the paper.